# Send signal to every thread in a given process

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals

`kill(2)` sends a signal to an arbitrary thread in the given process. `tgkill(2)` sends a signal to a specified thread in the given process. Is there a way to send a signal to every thread in a given process, other than iterating over the tids and `tgkill`ing each one?